# Hitting the ctrl button lowers my volume

Tags: windows, audio, keyboard

I have tried googling this and no one else seems to either have this problem, or find it to be a problem, but it is very annoying to me.  Everytime I accidentally hit my ctrl key by itself on my keyboard (I am using windows 7) my volume automatically lowers to a very low volume and then I can't hear anything.  It's very annoying whenever I am on a game and/or on skype and I accidentally hit ctrl and then I can't hear anything or anyone!!  How can I turn this feature off?

I've tried purposely hitting the ctrl key by itself, and it still reduced the volume.  I've bought a new keyboard since then, and it still does it.  It also happened on my old computer (which had windows 7 as well) and they are both HP computers.  It happens for both the left and right ctrl keys.

Comment: Does it do it while Windows is in Safe Mode?

Comment: Good question from @techie007. Do you know how to go into safe mode? Doing so will serve to eliminate 3rd party software as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The times that I've had things like this occur, another key was stuck on the keyboard. Try hitting other keys firmly a few times, particularly keys that are related to volume.

Comment: None of my keys are stuck.  I've tried checking it by making sure no other keys were being hit on my keyboard and just hit the ctrl key by itself, and the volume reduces.  I've even bought a new keyboard after my old one died and it still does the same thing.  I think the same thing also happens on my other computer as well, but I haven't used it enough in a long time to remember if it happens on there, too.

Comment: @Cassandra Please edit your question and add some of this info to it. Knowing you tried other keyboards and the keyboard on other computers is important information.

Comment: I thought it would be more commonly known to people and wouldn't need all this extra info.  Why am I the only one who experiences this problem?

Comment: @Cassandra - Have you reinstalled your operating system.

Comment: Why did this answer get a downvote? This is a legitimate possibility. Just because it didn't solve the problem doesn't mean that it's a poor answer.